# Python any() method results

Tags: python

Im wondering how the following result will yield True?

```
>>> x=['0']
>>> valid_diff=['0','1','2','3']
>>> result =any(x for each in x if x in valid_diff)
>>> result 
False
```

I would the expect the result to be True as the first element itself will be True.

Any thoughts, Im sure im missing something here..

Comment: This is incorrect: you are never using each, so it doesn't matter what the values are.

Comment: `for each`? Is that really what you meant?

Comment: Also, if you're going to do this, you might want to turn `valid_diff` into a `set`.  That will take this from an O(N*M) operation to an O(N) operation (where N = len(x), M = len(valid_diff))

Comment: After reading all the answers and getting very confused, I'd say you should rename `each` variable urgently... Even this comment got confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the typo I think there's no need of storing `each` here, just use:

```
#returns True if any item in x is found in valid_diff
>>> any(each in valid_diff for each in x)
True
```

or strictly sticking to what you were trying to do then use this:

```
any(each in valid_diff and each for each in x)
#will return `True` only if any item found in valid_diff is a Truth value as well.
```

[Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: This gives a different result if the first `each` that is `in valid_diff` is falsy. Not a concern with OP's sample data, I honestly doubt it matters for most problems, and it's meaningful this way, but it can't hurt to be aware.

Comment: @delnan Good point, I think if we stick to what OP was trying then 
`any(each in valid_diff and each for each in x)` seems correct.

Answer (score 6):

You have made a typo with your variable names,
you should be checking `if each in valid_diff` not `if x in valid_diff` and `each for each` not `x for each`

Comment: To expand on that: `if x in valid_diff` is looking for `['0']` in the list, not `'0'`, so obviously doesn't return anything]

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax:

```
>>> result =any(each for each in x if each in valid_diff)
```

Comment: Or to be less confusing, `result =any(xitem for xitem in x if xitem in valid_diff)`. I think the OP is under the illusion that `for each` means something special.

Comment: Right. Though, I only aimed to correct his syntax as per the variables he used.